# Try and Except in a generic form in python

Tags: python

```
mydict = {'USD':'UnitedStates','GBP':'UnitdKingdom','CAD':'Canada','AUD':'Australia'}

for key in mydict:
    try:
        print("The currency is", key)
        print(calendar_all['EURO'])

    except:
       print("Oops!",sys.exc_info()[0],"occured.")
```

Output:

```
The currency is USD
Oops! <class 'KeyError'> occured.
The currency is GBP
Oops! <class 'KeyError'> occured.
The currency is CAD
Oops! <class 'KeyError'> occured.
The currency is AUD
Oops! <class 'KeyError'> occured.
```

Above I dont want to print 'keyError' many times. It should be once if the key is not available in dictionary. In above case, I mentioned 'Euro' as key. It should give me error without writing any key which are not present in dictionary. I reframed my question. Hope you understood.

Comment: The code shown doesn't generate *any* `KeyError`. It *can't* generate a key error, both because you never perform any indexing operation and because (if you meant to do something like `mydict[key]` in the loop) the lookup will succeed by definition of a `dict_iterator`.

Comment: There are at least three options (print only after the first exception, print only after the last exception, and break the loop after the first exception), and which would be desirable not at all clear from the code shown.

Comment: I updated my query. Please check again.

Comment: Is it always the same key on each iteration? Just try the lookup once *before* the loop.

Comment: No. If key is out of dictionary then it should show key error without writing any specific key which is not there in the dictionary.

Comment: Based on your update, what does `mydict` have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

Just [break](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) the loop:

```
for key in mydict:
    try:
        print("The currency is", key)
    except:
       print("Oops!",sys.exc_info()[0],"occured.")
       break
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Error happened many times, that why you get it printed many times. If you want to exit execution when it happens the first time, you could add a `break`:

```
for key in mydict:
    try:
        print("The currency is", key)
    except:
       print("Oops!",sys.exc_info()[0],"occured.")
       break
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt the lookup *once*, prior to the loop:

```
mydict = {'USD':'UnitedStates','GBP':'UnitdKingdom','CAD':'Canada','AUD':'Australia'}

try:
    k = calendar_all['EURO']
    for key in mydict:
        print("The currency is", key)
        print(k)
except KeyError:
    print("Oops! KeyError occurred")
```

It could be cleaner to move the loop out of the `try` block altogether, especially if the loop can generate an unrelated `KeyError` (which this one can't, but this is a pretty artificial looking example. It's not clear what context you are actually working in.)